# Contribute function to model in custom Django model field?

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to contribute a function to a Django model within a custom model field definition?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Not entirely following what you are looking to do.

Comment: I don't think you can, or even should. Django fields map db columns to Python classes/objects. The function should be defined in those classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using the undocumented `contribute_to_class` function that is part of Django model fields it's possible to add attributes, functions and field specific signals to the parent model.

An example of this is visible here:

https://github.com/mogga/django-positions/blob/master/positions/fields.py

*(snippet below)*

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name ):
    super(PositionField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name)
    for constraint in cls._meta.unique_together:
        if self.name in constraint:
            raise TypeError("%s can't be part of a unique constraint." % self.__class__.__name__)
    self.auto_now_fields = []
    for field in cls._meta.fields:
        if getattr(field, 'auto_now', False):
            self.auto_now_fields.append(field)
    setattr(cls, self.name, self)

    def _position_move(instance, up):
        collection = self.get_collection(instance)
        cache_name = self.get_cache_name()
        position = getattr(instance, cache_name)[0]
        if up:
            collection = collection.filter(**{'%s__gt' % self.name: position})
        else:
            collection = collection.order_by('-%s' % self.name).filter(**{'%s__lt' % self.name: position})
        try:
            replacement = collection[0]
        except IndexError:
            return
        current, updated = getattr(instance, cache_name), getattr(replacement, cache_name)
        setattr(instance, cache_name, updated)
        setattr(replacement, cache_name, current)
        instance.save()
        replacement.save()

    def position_down(self):
        return _position_move(self, up=False)

    def position_up(self):
        return _position_move(self, up=True)

    setattr(cls, 'position_down', position_down )
    setattr(cls, 'position_up', position_up )

    pre_delete.connect(self.prepare_delete, sender=cls)
    post_delete.connect(self.update_on_delete, sender=cls)
    post_save.connect(self.update_on_save, sender=cls)
```